# Trouble with CSS transition between height:100px to auto

Tags: css, height, css-transitions

A `div` of a fixed height contains an element with more content than it can contain.
When in an inactive state (mouse not hovering over it) this div will be at height 100px and the bottom of the content is visible.

When this `div` is hovered, all the content inside should slide down and be shown. I have tried many ways to achieve this, applying `top` and `bottom` declarations, using `max-height` and using other methods.
NB: Content inside is of unknown/varying height

However, all of my methods thus-far have been unsuccessful in creating the required effect.

Here is a link of one of my methods:
http://jsfiddle.net/fLuHL/ 
It slides up instead of down.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain if this is what you're after, but... [updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/fLuHL/2/)

I added `top` properties to the css.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I was looking for something like that, however, the content inside is of unknown/varying height so I wouldn't be able to specify a numerical value (I forgot to mention this earlier, ammended).

Answer (score 0):

Since transitions do not take height=auto into account, I usually use translateY to achieve the same effect.

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/5oL3gf7n/

I only change the CSS of your code into:

```
.post-container {
display: block;
height: auto;
position: relative;
margin-top: 0;
z-index: 496;
transition: transform .5s;
    -moz-transition: transform .5s;
    -webkit-transition: transform .5s;
    -o-transition: transform .5s;
transform: translateY(calc(100px - 100%));
}

.text {                        
background-color: #666 !important;
padding: 20px;
}

.post-container:hover {
transform: translateY(0);
}
```